# Django EC2 deployment with wsgi and Apache

Tags: python, django, apache, amazon-ec2, mod-wsgi

I have a micro instance on EC2 with Django installed there. I've also installed mod-WSGI, PostgreSQL, etc following several tutorials.
Finally, I pulled my project from bitbucket and started Apache on my EC2. Unfortunately, the only thing I have is the default Apache page and I've already spent a day and night reading and trying to figure out what am I doing wrong.

my_project is in `/home/ubuntu` dir. In it's folder I have `wsgi.py` file:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_project.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

This is my `.conf` file stored in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`:

```
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost *:80
WSGIPythonPath /home/ubuntu/my_project/

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/my_project
    ServerName www.ec2-54-***-104-**.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
    ServerAlias ec2-54-***-104-**.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
    ErrorLog /home/ubuntu/my_project/apache/error_log
    CustomLog /home/ubuntu/my_project/access_log_common

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/my_project/wsgi.py
    Alias /static/ /home/ubuntu/my_project/static/

    <Directory /home/ubuntu/my_project/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/ubuntu/my_project>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

When I'm trying to

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

and instead:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```

It works fine and I'm able to connect to my app from a browser with IP as URL.
It gives me understanding that the `setting.py` file is fine (am I right?) and the problem is or in `wsgi.py` or `httpd.conf`.

When I stop my development server and start Apache again, I get the default Apache page. Can you help me please to find what's wrong with my files?

Permissions for apache:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-**-**-69:~$ ls -ld my_project/
drwxr-xr-x 10 www-data www-data 4096 May 26 19:51 project/
```

Answer (score 1):

You normally shouldn't use an IP address for ServerName, it has to be the hostname (FQDN) that the site is accessed as.

You are missing a WSGIDaemonProcess directive to correspond to your use of WSGIProcessGroup.

It is bad security practice to set DocumentRoot to be where your source code for your application is.

Finally, stuff under a users home directory is not usually accessible to the user that Apache runs as.

Suggest go back and review the mod_wsgi deployment documentation on the Django site again for a start.

Comment: Hello and thank you for reply!
I added some changes in my httpd.conf file. I put new ServerName and Alias, I also changed mod_wsgi from Daemon Mode to standart and added WSGIPythonPath to the root dir of my site.

Then, Ive checked rights on my root folder. I added what I have in the end of my topic. Everything is fine as I can see... But I still have Apache Default Page... Any other advices please?

Comment: What URL are you accessing the site with? Add a syntax error into your Apache configuration file and try restart Apache to even see whether it is reading the file you are editing.

Comment: Thank you for pointing at the problem that Apache not even reading my wsgi script. My mistake was I didn't create virtualhost in 'sites-available' inside my apache dir. Now everything works just fine!