# How to setup the Apache with Django

Tags: python, django, apache, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to setup Django with apache on an AWS EC2 instance.

This is 000-default.conf under /etc/apache2/sites-available looks like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName  mysite
ServerAlias mysite.com
ServerAdmin mysite@gmail.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite
WSGIScriptAlias /mysite /var/www/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py

ErrorLog /home/ubuntu/apache/errors/error.log
CustomLog /home/ubuntu/apache/errors/custom.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

My Django project is under `/var/www/`
My python location `/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin/python`

When I access the site this is what I get.

[image]

Comment: I advise you to switch to Nginx. You can check [this](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/) guide to deploy Django application with Nginx, Gunicorn and Supervisor.

Answer (score 0):

In the image that you shared, it shows a directory listing as you have no index file set for the root of your virtual server. You probably [don't want your data files exposed to the world](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23876947/django-ec2-deployment-with-wsgi-and-apache).

To display your Django project when requesting the mysite.com root, consider setting up WSCGI using the WSGIDaemonProcess directive. You'll probably want to set up some additional directories for static resources, too. Some simple directory permissions in your VirtualHost configuration and access permissions for your project data files should help get things running safely and reliably.

Check out this [HOWTO for setting up Apache to serve up Django](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04#configure-apache) written by someone awesome at DigitalOcean (skip down to the Configuring Apache section). Though the documentation I provided is not geared specifically to amazon-ec2, the Apache section should be enough to get you running. Please let me know how it works out.